# Python Sum with 3 nested list and empty list Explanation

Tags: python, sum, python-3.8, operation

```py
l = [ [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] ]
sum(l,[])
```

Output ist

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

**I don't know why it works like this.**

I tired the two below

```py
[].__add__(l) # First Try


[] + l # Secodn Try
```

In both cases, the output was as follows.

```py
[[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]]
```

I don't know what the difference is from the sum operation.

My python version is 3.8.12

Comment: `__add__` and `+` are both adding the elements of your list to an empty list.  Your list contains one element, so you get the same info.  `sum` is adding the elements of your list to each other.  Your list contains one element, so the result is that one element.

Comment: What do you want to achieve i.e. expected output or do you want to know the behaviour of your code ?

Comment: My purpose is to understand the principle of why an empty list is concatenated when sum operation is performed.

Comment: The `+` operator with two lists concatenates them

Answer (score 1):

`sum` takes a list of values and adds all of them together. E.g. for a list of numbers:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
sum(l)
```

does:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3
```

As you see, the outer list does not appear in the operations nor result.

Now, with your example:

```
l = [ [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] ]
sum(l, [])
```

that's concatenating *all the values in `l`*:

```
[] + [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
```

Which is not the same as:

```
[] + [ [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] ]
```

Comment: Fully understood.
Thanks for answering the question. It's perfect!

Answer (score -3):

If I understand correctly you want to add 1 to every item in the list, if so this code should work.

```
x = [[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]]

for i in range(len(x[0])):
    for j in range(len(x[0][i])):
        x[0][i][j] += 1

print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. But you should get more experience with Python, because you have completely misunderstood the question.